# How to remove a portion of string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to remove word `Test` and `Leaf` from the specified string beginning only,not from the other side,so string `Test_AA_234_6874_Test` should be `AA_234_6874_Test`,But when i use `.Replace` it will replace word `Test` from everywhere which i don't want.How to do it
This is the code what i have done it

```
string st = "Test_AA_234_6874_Test";
st = st.Replace("Test_","");
```

Comment: `String.Join("",st.Skip(5))` FYI, poor performance. Substring is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex to do this. The third argument of the regex [replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) specifics how many times you want to replace.

```
string st = "Test_AA_234_6874_Test";
var regex = new Regex("(Test|Leaf)_");
var value = regex.Replace(st, "", 1);
```

Or if the string to replace only occurs on the start just use `^` which asserts the position at start of the string.

```
string st = "Test_AA_234_6874_Test";
var regex = new Regex("^(Test|Leaf)_");
var value = regex.Replace(st, "");
```

If you know that you allways have to remove the first 5 letters you can also use [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) which is more performant.

```
string st = "Test_AA_234_6874_Test";
var value = st.Substring(5, st.Length - 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking whether the string starts with "Start" and/or ends with "Trim" and decide the end and start positions you'd like to maintain. Then use Substring method to get only the portion you need.

```
public string Normalize(string input, string prefix, string suffix)
{
    // Validation
    int length = input.Length;
    int startIndex = 0;
    if(input.StartsWith(prefix))
    {
        startIndex = prefix.Length;
        length -= prefix.Length;
    }

    if (input.EndsWith (suffix))
    {
        length -= suffix.Length;
    }

    return input.Substring(startIndex, length);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is by using a Regular Expression like so.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;

namespace RegExTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "Test_AA_234_6874_Test";
            var matchText = "Test";
            var replacement = String.Empty;

            var regex = new Regex("^" + matchText);

            var output = regex.Replace(input, replacement);

            Console.WriteLine("Converted String: {0}", output);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

The `^` will match text at the beginning of the string.

Comment: In _my_ mind, the words "simple" and "regex" (let alone "performance") never matched.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression.

```
        var str1 = "Test_AA_234_6874_Test";
        var str2 = "Leaf_AA_234_6874_Test";

        str1 = Regex.Replace(str1, "^Test", "");
        str2 = Regex.Replace(str2, "^Leaf", "");
```

Regex.Replace parameters are your input string (str1), the pattern you want to match, and what to replace it with, in this case a blank space. The ^ character means look at the start of the string, so something like "MyTest_AAAA_234_6874_Test" would stil return "MyTest_AA_234_6874_Test".

Answer (score 1):

```
string wordToRemoveFromBeginning = "Test_";
int index = st.IndexOf(wordToRemoveFromBeginning);

string cleanPath = (index < 0) ? st : st.Remove(index, 
    wordToRemoveFromBeginning.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna use some very simple code here

```
string str = "Test_AA_234_6874_Test";
string substring = str.Substring(0, 4);
if (substring == "Test" || substring == "Leaf")
{
   str= str.Remove(0, 5);
}
```